# Where I can see tokens of native google apps

Tags: google-admin-sdk

On this page:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list
 I can see all tokens from applications that installed on my devices , that authenticate to google services , however I don't see here tokens of native google apps , like gmail , drive google calendar, etc.
 Where I can see tokens of this apps ?

Comment: I think that method only applies to 3rd party applications as mentioned in [Token Overview](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens) "The Directory API allows you to audit access tokens that have been issued to 3rd party applications using the OAuth protocol"

Comment: Thanks for reply , but i need official statement from google . 
The problem is that I have logs from my  customers , where I can do see tokens for this app ( at least these apps have same names )